# Unable to install Mobile Client Software Factory July 2006 (refresh)

Tags: design-patterns

I'm trying to install Mobile Client Software Factory July 2006 (refresh) on a XP OS.  But it is failing with an error message

> This installer requires the Guidance Automation 
>                Extensions, June 2006 CTP or later, which is not present
>                on the computer. Please install it and try again.

But I've installed **Guidance Automation Extensions** and **Guidance Automation Toolkit For VS2008**  using the following installers available in the following location:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/aa718949.aspx

Can someone suggest me how to sort out this installation error?

Comment: this problem is so frustrating. Tried all the possible ways that I know. Still not able to install :(

Answer (score 0):

I've had to uninstall everything and reinstall in the correct order. Do you have the device emulator all setup with virtual pc and active sync installed?

Comment: I think, I've not followed the installation order. May be that could be the problem. I'll try again.